# Can a validator get access to the custom form control's component it is applied to?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a custom form control, which is used by the parent form component in the following way:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <app-custom-form-control formControlName="custom"></app-custom-form-control>
    </form>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app-form.component.scss']
})
export class FormComponent {
  constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      custom: ['']
    });
  }
  form: FormGroup;
}
```

There is a need to implement a custom validator for this component, such that it'd have access to the `CustomFormControlComponent` and can validate its internal state. Unfortunately, for my use case just assessing `form.controls.custom.value` is not enough.

Is it possible to achieve in Angular?